# Would landscape left/right make difference when developing Google VR CardBoard Game with Unity?

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I'm trying to make a simple VR cardboard game using Google VR SDK for Unity. I'm really confused about the problem as my title. **Will the values got from**

```
GvrViewer.Instance.HeadPose.Orientation.x;
```

**change when the orientation of smartphone change from Portrait to Landscape Left/Right?**

The following code works in Unity demo (after press play button and use alt+right-click to trigger head movement simulation), but I don't have a cardboard so I'm not sure whether it will still work on smartphone with landscape left or right attached to a cardboard.

```
private void Update()
{
    // forward if the value is positive.
    float forwardValue = GvrViewr.Instance.HeadPose.Orientation.x;
    // turn left if the value is negative.
    float turnValue = GvrViewr.Instance.HeadPose.Orientation.y;
}

private void Move()
{
    Vector3 movement = transform.forward * forwardValue * m_Speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Apply this movement to the rigidbody's position.
    m_Rigidbody.MovePosition(m_Rigidbody.position + movement);
}

private void Turn()
{

    // Determine the number of degrees to be turned based on the input, speed and time between frames.
    float turn = turnValue * m_TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Make this into a rotation in the y axis.
    Quaternion turnRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, turn, 0f);

    // Apply this rotation to the rigidbody's rotation.
    m_Rigidbody.MoveRotation(m_Rigidbody.rotation * turnRotation);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a quaternion field. Accessing an individual component of a quaternion is typically not a meaningful measure of direction. Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish with this code? There may be more robust ways to get that outcome.

Comment: @DMGregory: I think you're right, although I don't know what is quaternion...

Comment: Did you consider [looking it up](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)? It's not a secret code-word, it's a standard data structure used widely in game development.

Comment: @DMGregory: I've updated it again, I think my problem is simple and not related to math...